# Fit data points to specific shaped curve (maybe lognormal?)

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, regression

I have lots of data that always form [this shape of graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhnD5.png)

I have been looking for functions that match this type of curve and the only one that fits the shape seem to be the Log-normal distribution graph.

What I am looking to do is to create some type of regression for future data when I have just gotten [a bit of the graph.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMA7o.png)

I think that the data is always taking on this regular general shape so maybe it is possible.

I know the general formula for the lognormal curve but I'm not sure how to calculate sigma and mu in this case for the graph to fit my data?

Comment: You are not clear your data represents a probability distribution, i.e. the area under the curve is 1. If it is then you can use maximum likelihood estimation to fit the parameters and this has the benefit that you can also get an approximate error estimation of the fit.

Comment: @user121049 I totally forgot about that. My data isn't, but it IS approaching 0, so a k value before [this formula I'm using](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/ef80ddef904b7c4079c6346c4ccc6b382d93c17f) should maybe work? I was testing this, combined with a shifted x input [seem to be working in theory](https://i.imgur.com/g1u9KXU.png). Progress at least.

Comment: By "graph" in "this shape of graph" do you mean a histogram?  If so, then with "lots of data" you should consider kernel density estimation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).  That way deviations from a lognormal probability density can be better fit.  With lots of data one doesn't have to be tied down to a restricted shape.

Comment: @JimB Thing is that I don't necessarily need a density function at all. i just need a curve that looks very similar to that of the lognormal curve to try to predict future data from the one that is generated. So far the lognormal one is the one that fits the best when trying out different parameters ([link to image](https://i.imgur.com/g1u9KXU.png))

What I really want to do is some type of regression in Python to fit this data, but I think learning more of the lognormal curve is a good way to start.

Comment: It is not at all clear as to the kind of data you have.  Do you have pairs of numbers that would be used in a regression or do you have single numbers that have been used in a histogram?  Those are two very different situations.  Maybe a sample of your data would be helpful.

Comment: @JimB I am sorry I have a lot of data actually. [Here is my entire set for the graphs posted above.](https://pastebin.com/F9cFYueE) It consists of a UNIX timestamp (as in time when data was captures)(y axis) and a measurement of user attention at that moment (of an article from a website server). 


This general pattern appears for every article so the idea would be to be able to predict how an article will do (apex and fall lower than a certain value). So what I posted is raw data. [Here I took every 50th number or so](https://pastebin.com/Cr9pqBet) to make it easier.

Comment: This is the code i have been using: 

`k_val * (1 / (x * sigma * math.sqrt(2*math.pi)))  *  math.exp(  - math.pow((math.log(x)-mu),2)  /  (2*math.pow(sigma , 2)))` 


Like I said I need to calculate sigma, mu and k which I'm not sure can be done when I don't have the entire data set yet.

Comment: Thanks for making your data available.  That clears up a lot.  You have a time series with very correlated observations.  This question is much more appropriate for the StackExchange site CrossValidated.  Any regression you do would need to account for the extreme amount of serial autocorrelation.

Comment: Alright, will see if I will post it over there later. Started reading up on nonlinear regression in python and will give that a shot first!